# TFS Integration Tools - Wrong user in History

Tags: visual-studio-2012, tfs, tfsintegrationplatform

I have migrated several projects from TFS 2010 to TFS 2012 in our domain. I have a team project where after migration when I check the history in Visual Studio my user account is on many changesets. This is because my user account is running the TFS Integration Tools. What I don't understand is why it cannot determine the right user from the source team project for some users and hence puts my user account on the changesets in history and for some users it has no problems at all.

Both TFS servers are in the same domain and all the users in the team project on TFS 2010 are active and in the same OU in the AD.

Comment: Why not just upgrade in place the 2010 to 2012 server?

Comment: Due to many projects in my company, this is not an option.

Comment: Do you have them separate in collections? you can dettach/attach and we upgrade on attach.

Comment: They are in the same collection. I have done in place upgrades before. TFS Integration Tools is my only option here.

Answer (score 1):

I think I found a solution. If you create a team project on the destination server, make sure to add the same team members that exist in the team project that you want to migrate. Do this BEFORE you start the actual migration. I did this and now my history on changesets have the correct users name.